# how to convert toclocal to NSObject?

Tags: ios, delphi

In delphi, I have this procedure:

```
procedure addObserver(observer: NSObject; ...)
```

The observer must implement the key-value observing method `observeValue()`, so I tried to do it like this:

```
  IKVODelegate = interface(IObjectiveC)
    ['{B8C6720A-79B7-4FD6-B9E3-77594E905B3C}']
    procedure observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: NSString; ofObject: Pointer; change: NSDictionary; context: Pointer); cdecl;
  end;

  TKVODelegate = class(TOCLocal, IKVODelegate)
  private
  public
    procedure observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: NSString; ofObject: Pointer; change: NSDictionary; context: Pointer); cdecl;
  end;
```

However, the problem is that `TKVODelegate` is not an `NSObject` descendant, so I am unable to do the following:

```
addObserver(MyKVODelegate)
```

This is due to the fact that `addObserver` is waiting for an `NSobject`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use `TNSObject.Wrap()`, eg: `var myKVODelegate: IKVODelegate; obj: NSObject; ... myKVODelegate := TKVODelegate.Create; obj := TNSObject.Wrap((myKVODelegate as ILocalObject).GetObjectID); addObserver(obj);`

Comment: thanks remy ! it's was this !! why this in comment instead as an acceptable answer ?

Comment: Because I marked the question as a duplicate before I posted the comment.